# Upload and view multiple images in the same web page in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

[image]

This image shows what I need to do with ***codeigniter***. I have one page with several div tags. I need to upload images and show them at the same place. But there should be 3 different images and 3 different file locations for these images to save. I tried number of ways. Please anyone with idea help me.

My controller

```
 <?php
        if (!defined('BASEPATH'))
            exit('No direct script access allowed');
        class Upload_Controller extends CI_Controller
        {
            public function __construct()
            {
                parent::__construct();
            }
            public function index(){
                $this->load->view('file_view', array(
                    'error' => ' '
                ));
            }
            public function file_view()
            {
                $this->load->view('file_view', array(
                    'error' => ' '
                ));
            }
            public function do_upload()
            {
                $config = array(
                    'upload_path' => "./uploads/",
                    'allowed_types' => "gif|jpg|png|jpeg|pdf",
                    'overwrite' => TRUE,
                    'max_size' => "2048000", // Can be set to particular file size , here it is 2 MB(2048 Kb)
                    'max_height' => "768",
                    'max_width' => "1024"
                );
                $this->load->library('upload', $config);
                if ($this->upload->do_upload()) {
                    $data = array(
                        'upload_data' => $this->upload->data()
                    );
                    $this->load->view('file_view', $data);
                } else {
                    $error = array(
                        'error' => $this->upload->display_errors()
                    );
                    $this->load->view('file_view', $error);
                }
            }
            public function do_upload2()
            {
                $config = array(
                    'upload_path' => "./uploads/index2/",
                    'allowed_types' => "gif|jpg|png|jpeg|pdf",
                    'overwrite' => TRUE,
                    'max_size' => "2048000", // Can be set to particular file size , here it is 2 MB(2048 Kb)
                    'max_height' => "768",
                    'max_width' => "1024"
                );
                $this->load->library('upload', $config);
                if ($this->upload->do_upload()) {
                    $data = array(
                        'upload_data' => $this->upload->data()
                    );
                    $this->load->view('file_view', $data);
                } else {
                    $error = array(
                        'error1' => $this->upload->display_errors()
                    );
                    $this->load->view('file_view', $error);
                }
            }
        }
        ?>
```

My View

```
<div id="1">
<?php echo form_open_multipart( 'upload_controller/do_upload');?>
<?php echo "<input type='file' name='userfile' size='20' />"; ?>
<?php echo "<input type='submit' name='submit' value='upload' /> ";?>
<?php echo "</form>"?>
</div>
<div id="2">

<h3>Your file was successfully uploaded!</h3>
    <!-- Uploaded file specification will show up here -->
    <ul>

            <li>


            </li>
            <img alt="Your uploaded image" src="<?=base_url(). 'uploads/' . $upload_data['file_name'];?>">

    </ul>
</div>

<div id="3">

<?php echo form_open_multipart( 'upload_controller/do_upload2');?>
<?php echo "<input type='file' name='userfile' size='20' />"; ?>
<?php echo "<input type='submit' name='submit' value='upload' /> ";?>
<?php echo "</form>"?>
</div>

<div id="4">

    <h3>Your file was successfully uploaded!</h3>
    <!-- Uploaded file specification will show up here -->
    <ul>

            <li>


            </li>
            <img alt="Your uploaded image" src="<?=base_url(). 'uploads/index2/' . $upload_data['file_name'];?>">

    </ul>
    <p>
        <?php echo anchor('upload_controller/file_view', 'Upload Another File!'); ?>
    </p>
</div>
```

Comment: Your question is too broad. What exactly do you need answered? Please explain the methods you have tried.

Comment: I add my code above Mr.josephting

Answer (score 0):

Try This Code:

```
<form method="post" action="uploader/go" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="image1" /><br />
    <input type="file" name="image2" /><br />
    <input type="file" name="image3" /><br />
    <input type="file" name="image4" /><br />
    <input type="file" name="image5" /><br />
    <input type="submit" name="go" value="Upload!!!" />
</form>
```

Here Controller code:

```
class Uploader extends Controller {
function go() {
if(isset($_POST['go'])) {
  /* Create the config for upload library */
  /* (pretty self-explanatory) */
  $config['upload_path'] = './assets/upload/'; /* NB! create this dir! */
  $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png|bmp|jpeg';
  $config['max_size']  = '0';
  $config['max_width']  = '0';
  $config['max_height']  = '0';
  /* Load the upload library */
  $this->load->library('upload', $config);

  /* Create the config for image library */
  /* (pretty self-explanatory) */
  $configThumb = array();
  $configThumb['image_library'] = 'gd2';
  $configThumb['source_image'] = '';
  $configThumb['create_thumb'] = TRUE;
  $configThumb['maintain_ratio'] = TRUE;
  /* Set the height and width or thumbs */
  /* Do not worry - CI is pretty smart in resizing */
  /* It will create the largest thumb that can fit in those dimensions */
  /* Thumbs will be saved in same upload dir but with a _thumb suffix */
  /* e.g. 'image.jpg' thumb would be called 'image_thumb.jpg' */
  $configThumb['width'] = 140;
  $configThumb['height'] = 210;
  /* Load the image library */
  $this->load->library('image_lib');

  /* We have 5 files to upload
   * If you want more - change the 6 below as needed
   */
  for($i = 1; $i < 6; $i++) {
    /* Handle the file upload */
    $upload = $this->upload->do_upload('image'.$i);
    /* File failed to upload - continue */
    if($upload === FALSE) continue;
    /* Get the data about the file */
    $data = $this->upload->data();

    $uploadedFiles[$i] = $data;
    /* If the file is an image - create a thumbnail */
    if($data['is_image'] == 1) {
      $configThumb['source_image'] = $data['full_path'];
      $this->image_lib->initialize($configThumb);
      $this->image_lib->resize();
    }
  }
}
/* And display the form again */
$this->load->view('upload_form');
```

}
}

Comment: Thank you Mr.Harsh But in this code all images are saved to one folder. But I need one image saves only in one folder.

Comment: then how give folder name like 1,2,3 etc ??

Comment: I can't get you Hothi

Comment: bro you want make folder then upload image that folder ??